# Redirect from partial view to view with json data object

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have a json data object which i need to pass from partial view to view with REDIRECT.

Lets say below is my partial view ( _createEmp.cshtml ):-

```
Note:- This partial view is in different view or page

 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function () {
    LoadData();
 });

 function LoadData() {
  $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: baseURL + "Employee/GetEmpInfo",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     async: true,
     success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        **EmpData** = data; // EmpData object
     },
     error: function (error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
     }
     });
   }
 </script>

 <div>
     <input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="SetEmpInfo()" />
 </div>
```

And i want to transfer EmpData object to a different view (lets say NewEmp.cshtml), bind something in that view from passed "EmpData object" and open that view (or REDIRECT to view NewEmp.cshtml).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using ajax, you could return the URL from your action and have it redirected in javascript.

Without seeing your controller action you would need to do something like this:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult GetEmpInfo()
{
    // Do stuff
    return Json(new { success = true, redirecturl = Url.Action("GetEmpInfoSuccess") });
}
```

Then add something like this to your success handler in javascript:

**Javascript** (within your success handler)

```
success: function (data) {
            if (data.success == true)
            {
               window.location = result.redirecturl;
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Issuing a request to `Employee/GetEmpInfo` for getting the data and on success redirecting to other view - doesn't sound right

I think that you can do all this with one trip to server:

- Write an Action that receives all the the parameters that `GetEmpInfo` receives. Lets call it `NewEmployee`.
- If `GetEmpInfo` action is your code, **reuse** it's logic inside `NewEmployee` action to get `EmpData`. If it is not your code, you can use issue async request with `HttpClient` and get `EmpData` - *All this performed on the server*
- Once you have EmpData you should have everything your need to return a `NewEmp` view.

In this particular case there is no need in AJAX at all. You can use regular form submit in case that you need to post some data or just a redirect to `NewEmployee` action.